# Is it possible to catch error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" using do/catch block with swift 2?

Tags: swift2

Sample code:

```
if let result = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("UserAccount") {
  do {
    account = Account(
      id: result["id"] as! String,
      uid: result["uid"] as! String,
      username: result["username"] as! String,
      name: result["name"] as! String,
      image: result["image"] as! String,
      token: result["token"] as! String,
      client: result["client"] as! String
    )
  } catch _ {
    // Xcode show this warning:
    // 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block
  }
}
```

Any of the **result**'s keys can be nil.

Is there a way to just catch the error in case any of them is **nil**?

Comment: let Account init throw in case one of its parameters is nil. next use account = try Account(.....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that because the force unwrap of nil value does generate a `fatal_error` (which is not like throwing an ErrorType).

### Failable Initializer

But you can solve your problem simply adding a `failable initializer` to `Account` (it's easier if it's a `struct`).

```
struct Account {
    let id: String
    let uid: String
    let username: String
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let token: String
    let client: String

    init?(dict:[String:Any]) {
        guard let
            id = dict["id"] as? String,
            uid = dict["uid"] as? String,
            username = dict["username"] as? String,
            name = dict["name"] as? String,
            image = dict["image"] as? String,
            token = dict["token"] as? String,
            client = dict["client"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.token = token
        self.client = client
    }
}
```

Now

```
if let
    result = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("UserAccount"),
    account = Account(dict:result) {
    // use account here
}
```

### Throwing Initializer

If knowing that some field is missing is not enough for you, and you need to know which is the first missing field that stopped the initialisation of Account you can define a throwing initializer.

First of all you need a way to represent the error

```
enum AppError: ErrorType {
    case MissingField(String)
}
```

Next

```
struct Account {
    let id: String
    let uid: String
    let username: String
    let name: String
    let image: String
    let token: String
    let client: String

    init(dict:[String:Any]) throws {
        guard let id = dict["id"] as? String else { throw AppError.MissingField("id") }
        guard let uid = dict["uid"] as? String  else { throw AppError.MissingField("uid") }
        guard let username = dict["username"] as? String else { throw AppError.MissingField("username") }
        guard let name = dict["name"] as? String else { throw AppError.MissingField("name") }
        guard let image = dict["image"] as? String else { throw AppError.MissingField("image") }
        guard let token = dict["token"] as? String else { throw AppError.MissingField("token") }
        guard let client = dict["client"] as? String else { throw AppError.MissingField("client") }

        self.id = id
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
        self.name = name
        self.image = image
        self.token = token
        self.client = client
    }
}
```

Let's see how it does work

```
do {
    let dict:[String:Any] = ["id": "1", "uid": "1234"]
    let account = try Account(dict: dict)
} catch let appError {
    print(appError)
}
```

Output

> MissingField("username")

Comment: @ricardokrieg: Yes, at the moment there is a problem in Swift with `Classes` and `failable initializers` that force you to populate all the stored properties of the instance before returning `nil`. On there other hand, as we noted, `failable initializers` do work perfectly with `structs`. However if you don't have a good reason to use a `Class` (e.g. you need inheritance, or multiple part of your code must refer the same instance) you should prefer `structs` since they are much better by the performance and security points of view.